# Append local storage item in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to show a list of previous locations searched for. I am using session storage across the website, and local storage specifically for the search history.

Currently

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

    //saves name in local storage (for histoy list)
    localStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);

    //saves name in session storage - could be other things
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", currentWeather.name);

    // Retrieve session storage name to display back current location on search page
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

    // History
    var previous = {
        location : $("#name").val(), 
    }

    var record = JSON.stringify(previous.location);
    localStorage.setItem(previous.location, record); 

    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
    $("#record").append(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
    }
```

html:

```
<p>Location set to: <span id="name"></span></p>


<p>Record:</p>
<a id="record"></a>
```

So before trying to put into a list, I just wanted to get the locations to simply output. At the moment it is coming out like this:

""Manchester""Edinburgh

On chrome application tab, the session storage shows a key for name, and the latest name is appearing there. It also shows a blank key with a value of `""` and I don't understand why or how to fix this.

Comment: because of `$("#name").val()`. This is giving you `null` or empty string and you are using it here i-e `localStorage.setItem(previous.location, record); ` to set the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably because of `$("#name").val()` line of code in your script. Because you're trying to get the value of a span tag which is nothing or not available on the element used (`<span id="name"></span>`).

And afterwards you are using this as a key to set the data in local storage. As this was an empty that's why you see that `""`. Just replace `$("#name").val()` with `$("#name").html()` or whatever the way you can access the value you want to save in local storage.

Hope that helps

Thanks